# Download Facebook Page Posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm creating a service that has the objective of downloading the public content of a Facebook Page but I'm having issues with Facebook OAuth, application and all the stuff (why the hell facebook is sooooo complex?)

Well, I've created an application on Facebook, it's online and active. After that, I've downloaded Facebook SDK from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4 and at this moment I am trying to create a valid connection between the application running on my server and Facebook.

This is the function and the requires I'm using:

```
    session_start();
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurl.php');
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php');
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php');
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
    use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
        use FacebookAuthorizationException.php;
function consumeFacebook(){
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('my FBapp ID','my FBapp Secret');
    $session = new FacebookSession('myToken from the Facebook Application');
    $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      '/19292868552/posts',
      'GET'
    );  
    $response = $request->execute();
    var_dump($request);
}
```

And the error I get is the following:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'Invalid OAuth access token.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\dd-consumer\Facebook\FacebookRequestException.php:104 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dd-consumer\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php(254): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...', Object(stdClass), 400) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dd-consumer\index.php(63): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dd-consumer\index.php(71): consumeFacebook() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dd-consumer\Facebook\FacebookRequestException.php on line 104
```

Does anyone have any suggestion? Any workaround or even an easier way to accomplish what I need without the need of using FB SDK?

Thanks.

Comment: solved with: "$json = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/platform/posts?limit=100&fields=message,created_time,id&access_token=" . $appID . "|" . $appSecret);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an App Access Token to make this type of API call. The easiest way to do this is to use the app_id and secret.

You can then try something like this:

```
// create a session using app_access_token
$session = new FacebookSession( '{app_id}|{app_secret}' );

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

  // graph api request for public post data
  $response = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/19292868552/posts') )->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

  // print data
  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $response, 1 ) . '</pre>';

} else {
  // some error
}
```